# LibGDX: No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: white

Tags: libgdx, skin

I use a `uiskin.json` as my game skin. But I always get an error that there is `No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: white`. I searched across the web and SO but did not fond a proper solution. Maybe there is something wrong with my file?

```
{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
    green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
    white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
    red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
    black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$TintedDrawable: {
    dialogDim: { name: white, color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0.45 } }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round },
    toggle: { down: default-round-down, checked: default-round-down, up: default-round }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-font, fontColor: white },
    toggle: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, checked: default-round-down, font: default-font, fontColor: white, 
    downFontColor: red }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle: {
    default: { vScroll: default-scroll, hScrollKnob: default-round-large, background: default-rect, hScroll: default-scroll, vScrollKnob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox$SelectBoxStyle: {
    default: {
        font: default-font, fontColor: white, background: default-select,
        scrollStyle: default,
        listStyle: { font: default-font, selection: default-select-selection }
    }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SplitPane$SplitPaneStyle: {
    default-vertical: { handle: default-splitpane-vertical },
    default-horizontal: { handle: default-splitpane }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white },
    dialog: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white, stageBackground: dialogDim }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider$SliderStyle: {
    default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
    default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle: {
    default: { selection: selection, background: textfield, font: default-font, fontColor: white, cursor: cursor }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox$CheckBoxStyle: {
    default: { checkboxOn: check-on, checkboxOff: check-off, font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle: {
    default: { fontColorUnselected: white, selection: default-rect-pad, fontColorSelected: white, font: default-font }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Touchpad$TouchpadStyle: {
    default: { background: default-pane, knob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Tree$TreeStyle: {
    default: { minus: tree-minus, plus: tree-plus, selection: default-select-selection }
}
}
```

I am using the skin like this (if that matters in any way):

```
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skins/uiskin.json"));
```

Comment: I think your json is correct, you have uiskin.json, uiskin.atlas and the fonts in your asset folder also, https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data

Comment: I have the uiskin.atlas, the uiskin.png, default.fnt, default.json, default.png and the uiskin.json in my folder. If the json is correct where is my error coming from?

Comment: I never happened and I have to just those files, but in this direction http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=11155 sorted by copying all

Comment: So I have to download all these files? Isnt it possible to specify the needed files a bit more?

Comment: No you don't need all those files. Post your uiskin.atlas file. It needs to have some texture region called `white` defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eh been forcing the error that leaves you, and get it by editing the uisking.atlas
look at that, white is present in the file or download the file again

uisking.atlas

```
..//
selection
  rotate: false
  xy: 170, 44
  size: 1, 1
  orig: 1, 1
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
white
  rotate: false
  xy: 174, 48
  size: 1, 1
  orig: 1, 1
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

you probably do not have defined white in your Atlas file